# How is the value extracted from a Task in F#?

Tags: async-await, f#

If I make this call in F#

```ml
let mailServers = task{
  let! ms = lookupClient.QueryAsync(domain, QueryType.MX, QueryClass.IN, CancellationToken.None) 
  return ms
}
```

`mailServers` is a `Task<IDnsQueryResponse>`.

I would like to get at the `IDnsQueryResponse` value wrapped in the task. How can I change this async call to get the actual value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you already have the `IDnsQueryResponse` as `ms` within the `task` expression. Usually when you start working with `Task`s you want to keep working with `Task`s until all the work is done so you stay inside the `task` expression.

If you don't mind blocking the thread you can just call `mailServers.Result` to wait.

Comment: Ah yes! I see that now. So, does the inside the task { } block operate similar to the body of an async method in C#?

Comment: @MatthewMacFarland task { } blocks are similar to async methods and let! is similar to await.